# contact form in popup block

Tags: 6, blocks, emails

I want to show the contact form in popup. How should I actually do it? 
I tried to create a module and call the function in it. 
But I am confused on how to implement *hook_block_view()*

Is there any other way to this?

This is my first drupal project. 
And later do I realize that I am not having template.php in my theme folder.

This is what I have done.
 1. I had made a block in my page, named 'popup_this'.
 2. I made a module named 'popup' and made to display in this block.
 3. I had activate the module named 'contact' in the site. 
    It is called in the link '?q=contact'.
 4. I am trying to call this form in my custom module.

I don't know how to implement the function popup_block_view().

Thanking you in advance

Comment: Is your contact form a node?

Comment: Welcome to SO! 
Please add as much as information you can - for example, what was the module you used ? is "creating the first module" your question or "how to show a page in a popup" your question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to write a custom module. You can use the [popups api](http://drupal.org/project/popups) module. All you will have to do is assign the link a class called as "popups". Refer to the api if you want to do it the custom way as well using the popup api.

Summary of the module

> API for building modal ajax dialogs. Its focus is on putting forms
>   inside of ajax popup dialogs. Current example can present pages as
>   popups (of the lightbox type). This is amazingly useful for things
>   like confirmation pages. And the best part is it can be applied
>   retroactively to a page without needing to modify the generating
>   module, and (of course) it degrades gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

The Ctoosl Modal module, included on the [ctools](https://drupal.org/project/ctools) project, is the most popular way to popup modal forms on Drupal, with lots of addon modules. One of those addon modules is the [modal_forms](https://drupal.org/project/modal_forms) module which directly supports popup contact forms.